# Get all months with number of months and days from 2 date?

Tags: php, mysql, date

Here is my 2 mysql tables. In `clients` table is showing user connection date and in `clients_pay_bill` table showing in which month user is paid his/her bill from connection date (conn_date).

a) clients

```
clients_id    conn_date
=======================
1             2016-06-01     
2             2016-07-17
3             2016-06-22
4             2016-09-03
```

b) clients_pay_bill

```
cpp_id     clients_id    paid_month
===================================
1          1             2016-07-03 
2          2             2016-07-22
3          4             2016-09-09             
4          2             2016-07-22
```

Now I want to show all month**s** with number of days and months of which clients is not paid until current date.

For example :

`clients_id = 1` connection date (conn_date) is **2016-06-01** and he only paid **2016-07-03** month bill till now. So the sql query will be output following months:

```
2016-06
2016-08
2016-09
**2016-07 will not print because he already paid this months bill**
```

and I also want to show number of days and months e.g: 3 months some days..

I can't imagine how the sql query should look like ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you a bit different approach cause this one will kill you both logically and performance speaking. The way it should be done is to have records genreated in `clients_pay_bill` not when someone pays but when he/she should pay and as an addition to it there should be 2 columns: `due_date` and `paid_date`. So your table would look like this:

```
cpp_id     clients_id      due_month      paid_month
====================================================
1          1               2016-06-03     NULL 
1          1               2016-07-03     2016-07-03
1          1               2016-08-03     NULL
2          2               2016-09-22     NULL
3          4               2016-09-09     NULL   
4          2               2016-07-22     NULL
```

You could generate monthly **due note** via cron or if you prefer to stay in SQL than via events. After that you have simple query selecting which due note has `NULL` in paid_month cause if payment was done than you would update `paid_month` column.

Regarding days I am not sure what effect you would like to achieve (example would help) but having list of due notes it's already half way to make calculations regarding amount of days on these records (eg. with `DATEDIFF`)

Comment: Oh Really it's a great Idea but at first I have to insert all due_month right ?

Comment: Yes, you would have to set due_month first (eg. every month from `conn_date` or if you prefer you could insert due note on every 1st day of months)